# How is a Blocked Thread Rescheduled by the OS?

Tags: linux, unix

If I have a thread that is blocked on a socket for incoming data, how is it rescheduled back to the CPU? (in context of Linux). I am assuming the OS monitors the FD on a separate thread, and if there is data available, moves the corresponding thread to the RUNNABLE queue. However, I am not exactly sure of this. Also, how is the FD monitored - `poll/select` or `epoll`? Would appreciate a detailed explanation of this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, this is done using low-level waitable notifiable event objects. Different operating systems have different names for them, but the concept is the same.

Waitable objects are useful as a concept because they allow us to reason not only about sockets, but also files (via asynchronous file i/o apis) and any other situation where a thread is placed in a block-waiting state, and something must happen *outside of that thread* to unblock it.

Every socket, every file, every lock, mutex, or semaphore, every operating-system object that can cause threads to block-wait has such an event object associated with it. (Or is itself such an event object.) When your thread makes a call to an operating-system object which will need to block-wait, the operating system places the thread in waiting state, and notes that this thread is blocked on the associated event object. The call does not return for now; the scheduler gives the remainder of the time slice to some other thread that may have a use for it.

When an interrupt (or other event) occurs, as a result of which the operating-system object decides that the block-wait is over, the operating system checks to see whether a thread is associated with the event object, and if so, it places that thread in ready-to-run state, which means that the scheduler will soon allow that thread to resume execution, which means that the previously mentioned call will return to the caller.

Thus, there is no polling anywhere. Polling is a terrible thing to do under almost any circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's basically right.  When a packet arrives, the network hardware signals an interrupt.  The interrupt handler will process the packet through the network stack (or possibly queue it for later processing triggered by a timer interrupt or something, I'm not sure of the exact details here).  At some point, the network stack will decode the destination address and port, and notice that it matches a particular open socket.  That socket is associated with a list of threads that are blocked waiting for data.  So the packet's data will be stored in the buffer linked to that socket, and the relevant thread gets its state changed from "sleeping" to "runnable", and it's moved to the runnable queue.  When it gets scheduled, the thread sees the system call return and can proceed with its work.

The underlying mechanism is the same whether the thread is using `poll`, `select`, `epoll`, plain blocking `read` or `recv`, or anything else.  The choice between them is really just programmer convenience and/or performance, and some provide more features than others (like waiting on multiple different kinds of events), but they don't affect this particular issue.